# Rapidminer Studio: how to export ROC curve

Tags: rapidminer

Using RapidMiner Studio 6.5, the `X-Validation` operator is a part of my process. The operator automatically produces ROC curves as a part of validation results.

> How can I export the picture of ROC curves?

Windows' Print Screen command seems a bit too stone-aged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under

```
File -> Print/Export Images
```

You should find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As well as David's answer you can also install the Reporting extension from the marketplace and with a bit of configuring you can export the ROC curves into a report as you run your process.